# I put the code in Cron Events but can't update the status

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I put the code in Cron Events but can't update the status.
I am looking for a way to auto Change Status of Order from pos (custom status i am using) to pos-completed but after 1 minute Can it be done?
code for functions.php

```
add_action('order_status_pos-completed', 'finish_order_status_pos-completed', 10, 1);

function finish_order_status_pos($order_id){

if ( ! $order_id ) {
return;
}
global $product;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$time_order     = strtotime($order->get_date_created());
$time_current   = time();
$time_interval  = $time_current - $time_order;

//Case refresh page after 3 minutes at order, no changed status
if ($order->data['status'] == 'pos' && $time_interval > 60 ) {
    $order->update_status( 'pos-completed' );
}}
```

Comment: I don't know if there is an option to create action hooks based on custom status but seems like woocommerce_ is missing in hook. it should be woocommerce_order_status_pos-completed if woocommerce allows custom status hooks. 
you can also check the answer for alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the order_status_pos-completed hook doesn't exist because it's a custom status. why don't you use 'wc_order_statuses' filter to rename existing status ( ex : processing to pos & completed to pos-complete )

```
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wc_rename_order_status' );
function wc_rename_order_status( $order_statuses ) {
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        if ( 'wc-completed' === $key ) 
            $order_statuses['wc-completed'] = _x( 'POS Completed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $order_statuses;
}
```

Next you can use hook ‘woocommerce_order_status_processing’ & change the status to completed

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'finish_order_status_pos-completed', 10, 1);

function finish_order_status_pos($order_id){

if ( ! $order_id ) {
return;
}
global $product;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$time_order     = strtotime($order->get_date_created());
$time_current   = time();
$time_interval  = $time_current - $time_order;

//Case refresh page after 3 minutes at order, no changed status
if ($order->data['status'] == 'processing' && $time_interval > 60 ) {
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}}
```